# zeppelin form : load items dynamically in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

How to load dynamically items on an Apache Zeppelin form?

```
%spark
println("Hello "+z.select("day", Seq(("1","mon"),
                                    ("2","tue"),
                                    ("3","wed"),
                                    ("4","thurs"),
                                    ("5","fri"),
                                    ("6","sat"),
                                    ("7","sun"))))
```

I retrieve an array of strings from an SQL Spark request and I want to create the `z.select` with the array as input.

Comment: Please describe in more details what is your input and what is your expected output. Code in your question doesn't compile.

Answer (score 0):

Find solution ... I'm beginner with Scala and I didn't know how to create Array[(String, String)] object

```
//Create an array
val myArray = new Array[(String, String)](sizeofArray)
//Pass array to z.input form as Iterable
println("Hello "+z.select("day", myArray.toIterable))
```

Maxime